# When is the Kalman Filter state (un)observable?

Tags: kalman-filters

In Rudolf Kalman's [seminal paper](http://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Ewelch/kalman/kalmanPaper.html), the problem of filtering is defined as below (p. 2):

> We are given signal $x_1(t)$ and noise $x_2(t)$. Only the sum $y(t) =
> > x_1(t) + x_2(t)$ can be observed. Suppose we have observed and know
> exactly the values of $y(t_0), \dots, y(t)$. What can we infer from
> this knowledge in regard to the (unobservable) value of the signal at
> $t = t_1$, where $t_1$ may be less than, equal to, or greater than
> $t$? (...) If $t_1 = t$, this is called filtering.

Let's overlook the oddity of using symbol $t$ both as "time in general" and a particular assignable time, i.e. $t = t_1$. I'm trying to understand what "unobservable" means in this context.

Later in the article, when Kalman switches over to applying his filter to the Wiener problem (p. 6), he further remarks that it *"includes also the problem of reconstructing all the state variables of a linear dynamic system from noisy observations of some of the state variables.*

Is this lack of measurements for all state variables what is meant by $x_1(t)$ being "unobservable"? Should observations of all state variables (noisy or otherwise) be available, would the state then be considered "observable"? If not, what are the sufficient conditions for the state being "observable"?